# Neo4j APOC trigger, manual index - lowercase property values

Tags: neo4j, triggers, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have created the following Neo4j APOC trigger which adds node properties into the manual index:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('CREATE_NODES_TRIGGER', "UNWIND {createdNodes} AS n 
WITH n WHERE labels(n)[1] IN ['Title','Name','Character'] 
CALL apoc.index.addNodeByName(labels(n)[1], n, keys(n)) 
RETURN true", {phase:'before'})
```

When I perform the following query:

```
CALL apoc.index.nodes('Character','name:An*') YIELD node AS c, weight 
RETURN c.name, weight LIMIT 10
```

it correctly returns the data:

```
c.name  weight
"Annette Porter"    1.0
"Anke Bauernfeind"  1.0
"Angel's Henchman"  1.0
"Anna Slovatzka Marshall"   1.0
"Andrew Horvath"    1.0
"Angela Somes"  1.0
"An-Soo 'Alison' Kim"   1.0
"Annette Holman"    1.0
"Anita Wilcox"  1.0
"Anna Cerdick"  1.0
```

but in case of lowercased query `name:an*`:

```
CALL apoc.index.nodes('Character','name:an*') YIELD node AS c, weight 
RETURN c.name, weight LIMIT 10
```

the result is empty.

I think I should lowercase the property values before adding them to the index. Am I right?

If so, could you please help to improve the trigger in order to lowercase the property values:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('CREATE_NODES_TRIGGER', "UNWIND {createdNodes} AS n 
WITH n WHERE labels(n)[1] IN ['Title','Name','Character'] 
CALL apoc.index.addNodeByName(labels(n)[1], n, keys(n)) 
RETURN true", {phase:'before'})
```

Or please suggest another way how to solve this issue. Thanks!

**UPDATED**

I found the following property in neo4j.conf:

```
apoc.autoIndex.enabled=true
```

and added all nodes to the index:

```
CALL apoc.index.addAllNodes('movies',{
  Title: ["primaryTitle", "originalTitle"],
  Name:  ["primaryName"],
  Character: ["name"]}, {autoUpdate:true})
```

So, right now I have a question: will `apoc.autoIndex.enabled=true` only track and reflect changes on the already added nodes to the index(with `apoc.index.addAllNodes`) or it will also add the newly created `Title`, `Name` and `Character` nodes to the index also?

Comment: can you check your index definition? it should be created as "fulltext" index which also contains `case_insensitive: true`

Comment: also the labels(n) order is not guaranteed, in general something like `n:Title OR n:Name OR n:Character` is better than the IN check with a string array

Comment: Thanks ! This is the index config: `{  "type": "exact",  "provider": "lucene"}` How can I change it to fulltext ?

Comment: And how in case of `n:Title OR n:Name OR n:Character` can I change the following code `apoc.index.addNodeByName(labels(n)[1], n, keys(n))`.. especially the following part `labels(n)[1]` ?

Comment: Also, please check my updated question. I found the following property `apoc.autoIndex.enabled=true` and looks like this is the simplest way to go... but I'm not sure or will it automatically add the newly created nodes to the index also? Or do I need to use a separate trigger for new nodes and manually add them to this index?

Comment: I verified - `apoc.autoIndex.enabled=true` perfectly works for new nodes also. I think this is exactly what I need.